# dropzone square not showing

Tags: php, css, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm building an upload function (with laravel) to my webapp with dropzone. (dropzone.com).

But I don't see the upload square that should be there. 
This is my main master.blade:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title> @yield('title') </title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include roboto.css to use the Roboto web font, material.css to include the theme and ripples.css to style the ripple effect -->
    <link href="/css/roboto.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/dropzone.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

@include('standaard.navbar')

@yield('content')

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dropzone.js"></script>

<script src="/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // This command is used to initialize some elements and make them work properly
        $.material.init();
    });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my dropzone page:

```
@extends('standaard.master')
@section('name', 'Uploadcenter')

@section('content')
    <div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>UploadCenter</h1>

            <p>Hier kunt u eenvoudig en snel bestanden met ons delen. U hoeft het er alleen maar in te slepen!</p>

            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        <div class="well well bs-component">
        <div class="bs-component">
        </div>
            <form action="/{{ $user->id }}/files" method="post" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

But I only see this:

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dropzone shows that interface when an upload url is present

Comment: I've already set an upload url. That's working so that's not the problem.

Comment: Please, provide a demo.

Comment: turns out that the cdn css dropzone link was not working. https://cdnjs.com/libraries/dropzone